# VBA - Index and Match for multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with Control and 2 which are constant. From Sheet 2, based on unique values multiple new worksheets are created.

1. I have to take the balance from Control and insert the balance in the respective worksheets. Able to achieve this using Index and Match manually. But how to do I change it to change that in VBA automatically? My Index Match formula is
   `=INDEX(Control!N5:T8,MATCH('GBN'!Q2,Control!M5:M9,0),MATCH('GBN'!Q4,Control!N2:T2&CONTROL!N3:S3,0))`
2. In each of the worksheets except Control and Sheet 2, I need to sum all the values in column R (but it has one non-numeric value as well which is in the middle. This needs to be ignored. Find the next blank cell in column R and place the result
3. On the left of the Result in column Q i need the words Balance to appear.
4. Is there any way I can return the values of the Balance back to the Control sheet from the individual sheets. Note that it has 3 parameters. It needs to match the date, Sheet Name and under the column Balance

I have started the code as below

```vb
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim lastrow as Long
If ws.Name <> "Control" and ws.Name <> "Sheet2" Then

lastrow = ws.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
.Range("R10").Formula = ".Sum(Range(""R4:R")" ----- This is incorrect
```

Can anyone please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To try and solve issue 3, i tried the next row approach. Dim nextrow as Long nextrow = ws.Range("P"& Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row+1. But this did not help as well

Answer (score 0):

Taking them in order

1. As you are using VBA just insert the value directly
   e.g.

   GBN.Range(S3:S30).Value = Control.Range(N13:S43) 'Insert the correct ranges
2. Non-numeric values in cells are treated as zero in the `SUM` function so you could use something like this
   (insert the correct ranges)

   Dim LastRow As Long
   LastRow = GetLastRow(Sheet1)
   Sheet1.Range("R26").Formula2Local = "=SUM(R2:R" & LastRow & ")"

To get the last row in a sheet this is the function I use

```
Function GetLastRow(rg As Variant) As Long
'Find the last row used in a worksheet - regardless of where the data starts and ends
'and regardless of whether the data is contiguous or jagged
'Note use of Variant for the input range parameter
'This allows both worksheets and ranges to passed into the function
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = rg.Cells.Find(What:="*" _
                    , Lookat:=xlPart _
                    , LookIn:=xlFormulas _
                    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
                    , SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        lr = 1  'cater for a completely empty sheet
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    GetLastRow = lr
End Function
```

3. If you have already worked out where to put the result by working out the last row then you want "Balance" in the cell to the left - use `Offset` e.g.

   Sheet1.Range("R26").Offset(0, -1).Value = "Balance"
4. My comment for 1 above stands - just insert the values directly instead of trying to use WorkSheet formulae

Comment: Hey Thank you for the above. the issue is we need the code to run across all newly created worksheets which may differ. So i need it to be dynamic and run across all sheets.Also for point 1, we need the index match becasue it is dependent on multiple criteria

Comment: In VBA there is usually very little, if any, reason to use Worksheet functions. You can have multiple criteria - what is the problem with that?
Running across all newly created worksheets is also not a problem - just put the worksheet name into a variable and use that in the code that does the "stuff".
This is a good resource for some coaching in VBA (but watch out for the adverts for his courses) https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-articles/

Comment: Thank you. The worksheet names are not consistent. They may change everyday

Comment: Also not a problem. You can refer to sheets by number as well as name. You can also refer to the entire collection of sheets in a workbook and step through them.  Try the link I shared - you have a long journey ahead of you